# Materialized View Performance Issue

Tags: oracle10g, materialized-views

Am after some input on the following materialized view performance issue.

I have 2 materialized views, similar to the following:

```
create materialized view m1 as
  select stuff from tableone where adate = adate
  union all
  select stuff from tableone2 where adate = adate
  union all
  select stuff from tableone3 where adate = adate
  union all
  select stuff from tableone4 where adate = adate;

create materialized view m2 as
  select stuff from tableone where adate = adate;
```

The first materialized view takes approx 30mins to run, which is great. However, the 2nd materialized view takes well over an hour to run even though it is using one of the same queries from the first view and with a lot less data...any thoughts?

Comment: I can't help feeling there must be more to it than that.  Are you specifying other things like tablespace, physical attributes etc. in the real queries?

Comment: Perhaps you are running into some issue with [join factorization](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/optimizer_transformations_join_factorization).  Oracle may be re-writing the `union all` into a join, and as a side-effect fixing some other issue with the normal joins.  That explanation would only make sense if `tableone` was really a set of tables or views.  It might help to build a small, reproducible test case.  Also the explain plans may help us understand the issue.